# Connecting windows laptop to iMac

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows

I have Lenovo Thinkpad T490 from work and I got my personal iMac 5k 2017. I have got a dell monitor and use that as my primary monitor and want to use iMac as secondary monitor.

I have installed windows 10 on iMac using Bootcamp. I wanted to find out if I can use any sort of cable to connect both. My laptop got HDMI, USB-c charging port. 
I don’t use iMac as switching between windows and apple keyboard the buttons are different and get confusing, I want to use iMac as my second screen via cable.

So the question is can I and if so What cables do I need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the requirements to use iMac screen as a second monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: @Allan so it doesn’t?

Comment: That post spells out the requirements.  Even without that post, this post, as written has too few details to even speculate.  What ports on the ThinkPad, which model, what versions of the OS, etc.  the link posts tells you what’s required, so compare it to what you have.

Comment: Reading throught the linked post (and the Q&As referenced there) will give you much better picture about what is/is not possible and what the requirements are. Having said that: sharing a screen over WiFi usually is fast enough so maybe also add some details about what you currently have as a setup (including what's running on the iMac to allow screen access).

Comment: @nohillside I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use iMac as my second screen via cable.

You can’t.  The iMac doesn’t accept any video signal as input (the operating system doesn’t matter).  This model iMac does not support Target Display mode.

There are a couple potential products to turn your Mac into a secondary display for another Mac

- [AirDisplay for Mac](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/air-display/id419449718?mt=12)
- [Luna Display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/)

The last product that supported connecting from a PC to a Mac as a secondary display was Air Display 2, but has since been discontinued.