# Connect another mac as secondary display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen-sharing

I have two macbooks:

- MacBook Pro 2012
- MacBook Pro 2017 with touchbar

Recently I've got an idea to use 2012 as a secondary display.
I don't completely understand whether it's possible or not, the only info I found on this is
https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/imac-secondary-display/
It's said that this is possible if your second mac has thunderbolt or mini display ports. My 2012 does have it (mini display port).
So let's consider it's possible.

It's said I need mini display to usb-c adapter. It's ok but not quite cheap. So finally we reached my question.
I already have minidisplay to hdmi adapter. Now I'm wondering is it going to work if I purchase usb-c to hdmi adapter (since it's twice cheaper) and try to connect both adapters to each other?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unless explicitly mentioned in the official specifications for the machine, it can't.  For this machine it is https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649

You might find Synergy an interesting alternative as it allows you to use both machines at once.  https://symless.com/synergy

Comment: More specifically, this feature was only ever available on iMacs between 2009 & 2014. Link to 3rd party site as Apple seem to have removed all reference to the feature recently - https://applerepairstation.co.uk/Technical%20Desk/use-your-imac-as-a-display-with-target-display-mode/ The feature has also been completely removed from the OS since Mojave - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There’s product called [Luna Display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/) that a hardware solution that allows you to use a Mac or an iPad as a secondary display.

> Use any Mac as a second display — perfect for anyone with multiple Macs. It also works on older Mac models

I’ve personally seen this work - I wouldn’t use it for gaming, but as a secondary display it’s pretty good.

What you were looking at in the linked article is called Target Display Mode and you need a supported iMac to make that work.

Comment: yeah, I saw Luna project when was googling my question. It definitely solves my question. But I have some concerns about its performance since it has not only hardware but software components as well. I had an experience of using software solutions before (specifically apps.apple.com/app/duet-display/id935754064) and it was not the best experience (I connected iPad pro as secondary display then). There were often some freezes and slow reaction on user input. After Catalina was introduces I moved to its native solution of screen extension and it is the best solution I've ever tried.

Answer (score 0):

What was not supported officially before may now be supported. I'm trying out the Apple support docs with the title [Use your Mac as a Display](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-your-mac-as-a-display-mchl7d43ecb2/mac) and will report back.