# 24 inch iMac Early 2009 - Use as monitor via Firewire

Tags: display, imac, firewire

I'm trying to figure out how to use my old iMac as an external monitor for a windows laptop.  I've read that it's impossible since its Mini DisplayPort doesn't accept input, but it seems like there's a possibility that nobody has considered.  Firewire 800 seems to be capable of carrying video signals, and the machine has one of these ports.  Is it possible to turn this old machine into a monitor using this port, or is there a good reason why no one has suggested this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the requirements to use iMac screen as a second monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor)

Comment: No, I've confirmed that this machine doesn't support Target Display Mode because the Mini DisplayPort only supports output and not input.  If this is a software issue, I could install Linux and make the port accept input, but I don't think it's a software issue.  So I'm trying to figure out if there's any third party software that will display video from the Firewire port.

Comment: Do you know of any  DisplayPort (DP or mDP) ports found on computers that are both display out and video capture?  There's no Linux distro that will take a video output port and turn it into a video capture device.