# Using iMac 2008 as a monitor for Microsoft Surface 7

Tags: mac, display, windows

I am trying to connect an iMac 2008 to a Microsoft Surface 7. My iMac has a Mini Display Port.

Any idea how to connect the iMac to the MacBook Pro, to use as an external monitor? I think I need the USB C to Mini USB Cable (Mini USB to USB C Cable) 3.3 Feet in Black

Not similar to the link
[What are the requirements to use iMac screen as a second monitor - Target Display Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor-target-displa)

Comment: Please amend the question to explain *why* it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: The iMac on the other question is referring to a late 2019. I’m taking about a 2008 model

Comment: Did you read the answer as well? It covers all iMac models, not only the 2019 one.