# No Target Display for Catalina on iMac's -- How to roll back to High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, downgrade

Spent hours to figure out why iMac was not running Target Display mode. Got it, it needs High Sierra or **older**, stupid me, I assumed High Sierra or **newer**.

More and more older iMacs are getting (somewhat) obsolete. That is a shame we can really re-use them well, the screens are great. I just hate to throw away good working stuff.

Has anyone managed to roll-back a Catalina iMac with a trusted version of High Sierra, in order to keep using them as external screen?

Comment: I've removed the Linux part of the question, this is better asked on a Linux-focused site.

Comment: In addition, the source Mac (MacBook or otherwise) needs to have not only Catalina or _earlier_ but it also needs to be a model introduced in 2019 or _earlier_ as stated in [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204592) for the target display mode to work.

Comment: Aslo see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor-target-displa

Comment: IMHO "Would anybody know if Linux on iMacs would support an 'monitor modus function' or so" is better asked on a Linux site because it's more likely to get answers there. If you want to try your luck on AD, please ask a separate question for this.