# Connect iMac (27-inch, Late 2013) to MacBook Pro M1 Max

Tags: imac, usb, thunderbolt

Before I bought my new MacBook Pro M1 Max, I had MacBook Pro (Early 2015). I used my iMac (27-inch, Late 2013) as a target display mode for my photography work. I used thunderbolt to thunderbolt cable based on this [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

I used to press Command-F2 on the keyboard of the iMac and I would see the desktop of my MacBook Pro. But, I am not sure how to make the same setup work for my new MacBook?

I have tried to connect through HDMI cable, it didn't work. I ordered USB-C to Thunderbolt but I received Thunderbolt-3, that didn't work. I also tried Display Port to USB-C, it didn't work either. Only thing left to try is USB-C to Thunderbolt-1 cable, but I am not finding such cable.

Any idea how can I make this work, I don't want to loose my iMac. Appreciate any help and links to the cables that I should work with.

[This](https://youtu.be/WP1fnrHNuTE) YouTube video made 2009 iMac work with M1 laptops - so I am sure, there is a way for 2013 iMac IMHO.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck on a modern Mac. Apple have abandoned this technology. See  [What are the requirements to use iMac screen as a second monitor - Target Display Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor-target-displa)

Comment: How is she connect in the YouTube video that I shared? She connected 2009 iMac to new MacBook.

Comment: Sorry. If it was text I'd read it, but I'm not going to sit through a 10 minute video. If the detail is in there, then it needs extracting into a useable form.

Comment: I understand, there is text also in the description. But, nothing special as she just used Type C to Mini DP and the display would start working out of the box. No need to even click CMD-F2

Comment: The person in the video you referred to uses the mini DisplayPort on a late-2009 27" iMac to share a 2020 M1 MacBook Air's screen to the iMac. This appears to be a technique other than the Target Display Mode (which is OK as long as it works of course) but it looks like one needs a mini DisplayPort on the iMac for it to work. Only certain iMacs from 2009 and 2010 have a mini DisplayPort according to [this Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201736) and therefore that technique is unlikely to work with your 2013 iMac.