# Can I use a iMac 2013 as an external monitor to a MacBook Pro 2021

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac

I’ve tried using target display mode and AirPlay - neither seem to work. Am I missing something? Surely there’s a way to join the two…?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor-target-displa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tl;dr:** Its not possible. Your macbook is too new to support SENDING target display mode to another mac. Your iMac is too old to support RECEIVING airplay.

This is not possible. As stated in this [apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), the device projecting to the iMac in target display mode must be made before 2019. Target Display mode will not project to the iMac with your new MacBook pro-2021.

AirPlay only works for devices released after 2019. This means, funnily enough, your iMac can project its display onto your MacBook, since the 2013 iMac supports airplay, and your new MacBook can act as an airplay receiver. But alas, this most likely has no practical use to you.

My recommendation is to get a cheap 1440p monitor & just use that. If you want the quality of an iMac display & your techy, get an iMac with a failed motherboard but a working display & buy a [converter board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/154051591910) for the display online (such as ebay). This will allow you to connect to your iMac display via HDMI.

**Note: the link to the converter board I have provided is not guaranteed to work. I have done no research to find out if this works with 2013 iMacs. You must do your own research and verification if you want to buy a converter board.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and help! Much appreciated. I will stop trying/banging my head against the wall now and just buy another screen  .

Comment: @Gem if you found my answer helpful, could you kindly mark it as correct and upvote it?

Comment: @Gem I tried to do the same thing ages ago with 2 2013 imacs. It worked, but thunderbolt cables were so expensive that I just sold the other iMac & bought a 1440p monitor.