# Mac Mini 2012 & iMac

Tags: imac, mac-mini, app-store-connect

I have an iMac Retina 5K. I am frustrated running Apple Music and wish to run iTunes on an older macOS in my old Mini.

Can I connect the old Mini to my iMac and essentially use the iMac screen to run the iMac?

Comment: You may be able to use Home Sharing on the Mini, and then access the iTunes content over Wifi. But what will you do if/when the Mini stops working? Really you should fix your problem with Music.app. What's the problem there?

Comment: What you’re describing,  to use the iMac as a display for the mini is called [Target Display Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389357/119271).  Unfortunately, any iMac past 2014 will not support it anymore.

Comment: It sounds to me like BOB wants to use screen sharing to login to the Mac mini from the iMac. This might require a [HDMI Dummy Plug](https://www.amazon.com/Headless-Display-Emulator-Headless-1920x1080-Generation/dp/B06XT1Z9TF) for the Mac mini. If so, then I am fairly sure this question has been asked before.